# Select the CardView in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin, I have two `CardView` (https://github.com/tiger4589/Xamarin.Forms-CardView) within separate `Grid.Column`.

What I want to do is select a CardView (one at a time), which enables the Button.

How could I acheive this?

**.xml code for CardView**

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0">
    <cardView:CardView>
        <cardView:CardView.CardViewContent>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label 
                    Text="PIN"
                    FontSize="18"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
                </Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </cardView:CardView.CardViewContent>
    </cardView:CardView>
</Grid>

<Grid Grid.Column="1">
    <cardView:CardView>
        <cardView:CardView.CardViewContent>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label 
                    Text="QR Scan"
                    FontSize="18"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
                </Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </cardView:CardView.CardViewContent>
    </cardView:CardView>
</Grid>
```

**.xml code for Button**

```
<Button
    x:Name="FormButton"
    IsEnabled="False"
    TextColor="#4DABFE"
    Text="Submit">
</Button>
```

**UPDATE ON CollectionView**

```
<StackLayout>
    <Frame >
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding .}"
            SelectionMode="Single">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Text="Tokyo"
                               FontSize="20"
                               TextColor="Orange"
                   VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: I would suggest do this same thing  collection view

Comment: @RonakShethia thank for response. I looked into Xamarin Docs for `CollectionView`. The data has to be coming from `ViewModel` e.g. `CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Moneky}"`, but I don't want to get the data from ViewModel. When I removed the `ItemSource` or I just write `ItemsSource="{Binding .}"`, (because I want to provide the data on .xml page), the data isn't displaying.. why?

Comment: so can u tell me where are u getting the xml data if u are getting it in .cs file then u can used collectionviewname.ItemSource = yourxmllistdata

Comment: no, i mean this, as u see in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data, It asked to use the `<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}" >` and then `<Label Text="{Binding Name}" />`

Comment: it will get the data from `MonkeyViewModel.cs`.. but, I want this `<Label Text="Tokyo" />`.. and it isn't displaying any data on screen

Comment: I added the code above, kindly have a look.. thanks :)

Comment: got your problem wait will post the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your collectionview would look like this

```
 <CollectionView x:Name="MyCollection"
        SelectionMode="Single">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                           FontSize="20"
                           TextColor="{Binding ItemColor}"
               VerticalOptions="Center" />
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

Now you need to create a model Eg. MyDataModel which would have property as follow

```
class MyDataModel
        {
         public int ItemId{ get; set; }
         public string Title { get; set; }
         public string ItemColor { get; set; }
        }
```

now you need to init the list in your .cs file also u can do this view viewmodel but in your case you are using .cs
so it would look something like this in your constructor

```
var myList = new List<MyDataModel>();

Loop your XmlData List
eg. XmlDataList.ForEach((item)=>{ myList.Add(new MyDataModel{Title = item.properyinxml 
 })});

MyCollection.ItemSource = myList;
```

Comment: also add selection mode as single to select an item

Comment: `The name 'XmlDataList' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: XmlDataList is dataset of your xmldata which u told u are getting if you dont have so simple add item to myList.Add(new MyDataModel(Title = "MyTitle", TitleColor = "#fffff"

Comment: I get what u said and I also did, but I'm getting these 'doesn't containt' errors... On `myList.Add(new MyDataModel(Title = "Hello World"));`, I says `'MyDataModel' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments`

Comment: thanks for helping, just last question.. I'm trying to select the complete `CollectionView`, but can't, it's just selecting the label.. and if I want to change the OnSelect Color, I have to set it in custom renderer, right?

Comment: no follow the collection view document its mentioned there how u can change color